# Stretches and muscle work for Supination or Underpronation

Tags: running, stretching, knee-pain

I've recently had issues with my IT Band, did all the stretches and PT. And it did not work.
I recently decided to try out my old pair of running shoes(on a whim), that originally were bothering my knees(interior side). Amazing my outside IT Band seemed to be a lot better.

So, did some research, and may have realized I'm an under pronator, especially in my new shoes i bought that corrected my other knee issues. Looks like i went from Over-pronation in one pair to Under-pronation in the new pair.

I'm looking for ideas, stretching(pre-post) and particular muscle work that may help correct or alleviate the problem. I'm going next week to be properly fitted for shoes at a local running store.

So hopefully with the correct footwear, my new IT Band Strap, and some good running techniques i can put this issue behind me and enjoy the trails again.

Also, i see a lot of books on amazon about proper running technique, anyone read any of these and recommend one that shows how to train and practice proper technique, and maybe shows ideas to overcome common injures.

Thanks.

PS. i could not tag this topic correctly, not enough points. Not sure if someone can help with that.
(stretching supination under-pronation it-band)

---

**UPDATE 4.15.2013:** So its been a month since i last updated this. About 3 weeks ago i went and got a proper fitted running show and insoles. Definitely less cushioning and lighter.

I've ramped up to 3+ continues miles and 6 miles with a few 30sec walking breaks. And **NO IT Band pain! Woot.** Doing a few mins of stretching(before and after), leg muscle workouts(especially hips), jumping and stepping up on exercise box/platforms(about 18"). But most of all, I really believe it was the shoes over everything. Its expensive to get fitted, but all the time and money i spent on other remedies, it would have been cheaper.

For me, my problem looked to be Supination(bow legged) caused by improper running shoes, hopefully this will help other people out there.

Comment: Update: I used my older running shoes again last night on the treadmill, went 2 miles and no pain. Plus i am also wearing IT band strap above my knee. Going to rest a few days, and try an outdoor, hopefully push 3 miles. My newer shoes would cause sharp pain @ 1.5 miles.

Comment: Update: I tried running outdoor, on uneven ground. Used my older shoes, and gained and extra mile. So, the knee needs some rest and recover time, and its looking like the shoes are/were the main problem. Still experienced some discomfort and little pain, but that maybe partly do to it being injured and not healed. I'll update again a few weeks once i rest ny knee and get some proper runnign shoes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is alot of good info about running injuries and ITB syndrome, so I'll try to highlight some of the answers that will help to answer your question:

- **Regarding Warm-up**:

  @Ryan gives a good running warm up with video links in answering this question: [Best warm up for running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/best-warm-up-for-running/7403#7403).  Generally dynamic exercises are recommended prior to the workout.  Static stretching would be done post exercise, not before.
- **Regarding Possible Causes of Running Injuries:**

  @Ivo's answer covers both intrinsic and extrinsic factors to consider, including proper shoes and running surfaces etc.: [How to run without damaging your feet, knees or hips.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-run-without-damaging-your-feet-knees-or-hips/965#965) .

  With ITB problems two of the extrinsic factors to consider would be your shoes, as you have already identified, and the running surface. Consider the slope of the running surface to avoid stressing the side of your knee.  Run on alternate sides of the road to avoid one leg always being on the outer slope. As for technique, see below.
- **Regarding Strengthening Exercise:**

  You said you did all the stretches and PT. Hopefully your PT included hip strengthening exercises.  [This article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/05/04/us-leg-injuries-idUSTRE54342G20090504) discusses the role of hip muscle weakness in overuse lower leg injuries:

  > Stretching the hip muscles is important for runners as well, according to Ferber. However, he said, studies indicate that strengthening the muscles may be much more important when it comes to reducing injury risk

  With ITB syndrome, weak hip musculature should be addressed. [This video](http://strengthrunning.com/2011/02/the-itb-rehab-routine-video-demonstration/) gives some good ITB strengthening exercises.
- **Stretching and Myofascial Release** -

  This q/a that will give you additional info about: [ITBS](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/itbs-recovery-methods-techniques-advice/3802#3802). Here is a video link on how to [use a tennis ball](http://youtu.be/AAuv9BUq_yY?t=1m29s) for myo-fascial release that may help you get more specific than with a foam roller.
- **Running Technique**, here are 2 book links from our site's amazon store:

  1. [Dr. Nicholas Romanov's Pose Method of Running](http://astore.amazon.com/howtogetbackinshape-20/detail/0972553762) was already mentioned.
  2. [Chi Running](http://astore.amazon.com/howtogetbackinshape-20/detail/1416549447) is another running technique to prevent injury.  The book is good, but it may take going to one of their workshops to get the form: anterior to midfoot strike, minimalist shoes, and developing the skill of "body sensing" to identify causes of pain/injury.
- Barefoot or Minimalist - Many runners find switching to barefoot running eases pain.
- This study compares four [different types of running forms](http://www.chirunning.com/2012%20UNC%20Running%20Impact%20Study.pdf): "traditionally shod rearfoot strike,
  barefoot/minimalist anterior footstrike, Chi, and minimalist shoe rearfoot strike" (Pose runners were not included because they were unable to recruite enough for the study):

  > Traditional shoe wearers were 3.41 times more likely to report injuries than experienced
  >   minimalist shoe wearers (46.7% for traditional shoes vs. 13.7% for minimalist shoes, X²=77.4, 1df,
  >   p<.001, n = 888)
  >
  > Contacting the ground with a more anterior footstrike pattern may reduce eccentric knee work1 and possibly reduce the high number of
  >   overuse knee injuries commonly seen in runners.
  >
  > **Experienced minimalist runners reported fewer overall injuries** and fewer injuries
  >   specifically at the hip, knee, lower leg, ankle, and foot than did traditional shoe wearing runners.
  >   Chi runners also reported fewer injuries than did rearfoot striking runners. **Overall, runners who reported utilizing a more anterior footstrike pattern reported fewer injuries than rearfoot striking runners.**

Comment: The shoes maybe my biggest problem. I also started doing a particular exercise before running. Lay on your side, use one of those rubber stretch work bands, and do side leg lifts. I did min stretching, but a lot of side leg lifts the last 2 days. More post stretching. Going to look into your suggested pre-stretching.

Comment: You are welcome.  The side leg lift exercise that you are doing with the tubing is one of the ones in the video.  Sounds like you are on the right track.  And good luck on getting the right shoes.  Once I find a pair that works I buy a second pair online.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have a foam roller, get one!  They're great for IT band issues and warming up/loosening muscles.  I personally use a [Stick](https://www.thestick.com/) for the same thing (pre & post run muscle stretching) but I don't have IT band issues so can't speak to the efficacy of a Stick on the IT band specifically.

Comment: I did get a foam roller, did not help. the shoe selection seemed to be the biggest help so far. the more i read, the more i think there is no one or two magical solution for everyone, its going to be hit or miss til you find a solution. Its just aggravating to go thru the misses.

Comment: Hang in there!  A gait analysis is definitely going to help, or at the very least not hurt. :)  Have you tried looking into other running styles, such as mid-foot or forefoot strike?

Comment: I was just reading about barefoot running. Not sure i want to try it. I am definitely a heel striking in shoes. I was looking at my pair the other night, and the back edge of the heel is excessively worn. Hoping to find a good book on training to go more mid foot.

Comment: Plus i have very tight tendons and ligaments, poor posture. 6'3, when i look down to watch my feet occassionally, i notice my legs are bent, not slightly. like i'm running in a pre-squat position.

Comment: If you can find a Pose training coach (I found one at the local Y), it doesn't take long at all to re-learn the new stride.  I had literally one training session, spent about a week really really concentrating on what part of my foot was striking, and voila! all of a sudden it was pie.

Comment: For the tight tendons and ligaments, I wonder if a bit of yoga might help with that...