# Natural Running - less injuries or not

Tags: running, running-shoes

In context of running, one of the most discussed subjects over the last many years probably have been whether "Natural Running" will prevent injuries or actually be the source of injuries.

I have looked at the many, many references you can find on the web if you search for "natural running injuries" and to me it looks like you can easily confirm any initial views or assumptions no matter what you think of the subject.

With other words, it is extremely difficult to find objective investigation - let alone research - into this subject.

From discussions on my local running team, the general agreement seem to be that natural running is good for your legs in general - especially your shins, knees and hips - but it is bad when it comes to plantar fasciitis. Which kind of make sense to me, as your steps are shorter, but the archs under the feet must handle more pressure.

[As I have almost continuous problems with shin sprints, I wonder if I should try to switch. But I have also had some rather serious problems with PF in the past, which I really, really don't want to repeat..]

Thus the question: Are there any (conclusive) research in this field? Has anybody figured out if natural running is good, bad or just same-same?

Comment: You must have looked everywhere but here: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/293/experiences-with-barefoot-running

Comment: I did look at this question, but I'm _not_ asking about general experience in barefoot/natural running - I want to know about natural running vs injuries which is not covered in that question.

Comment: I had a minor problem with PF from barefoot running.  Totally general fitness advice - if you have a history of serious problems with PF too, I'd say that nothing good is likely to come of taking up barefoot running.  PF is nasty - you need your feet for almost any activity you're likely to do.  I have a friend who used to run ultra-marathons, developed PF, and is now permanently barred from all lower body sports (about the only thing he can do is kayaking).  My $0.02.

Comment: I think what I meant to say is that a study may tell you something about the average runner, but that isn't a substitute for understanding your personal history with injuries.  If you've had PF before, it's pretty smart to avoid variations of running that have a high risk factor for PF, regardless of how an "average" runner may respond to it.

Comment: The only conclusive research as to whether or not natural running will improve or aggravate your shin splints and/or plantar fascitis is to conduct research on you.  [This q/a](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11858/stretches-and-muscle-work-for-supination-or-underpronation/11862#11862) is about ITB pain, but includes info on research comparing different styles of running that found, "Overall, runners who reported utilizing a more anterior footstrike pattern reported fewer injuries than rearfoot striking runners."  And "Experienced minimalist runners reported fewer overall injuries."

Comment: @DavidR Honestly, I consider my PF "cured" and I usually run 30-40 km/week with no problems at all. Well... expect for a irritating Shin Sprint lately. I don't taking 6-8 month making the switch if I can "expect" less SS type of injuries in the future. And it could be fun trying something new as well..

Comment: I started experimenting with barefoot/VFF because of PF. Having done 20 marathons and ultras, I had to slow down for a while. 18 months later, I haven't felt any PF-caused pain for a long time. The price: my speed declined more 1 minute per mile. My shin muscles grew so much that now they are bigger than my biceps. Also I had to strengthen my core, especially the obliques. I have completed a marathon recently, going for an ultra later this year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to keep your knee problem free in the long run for a distance runner?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13365/is-there-any-way-to-keep-your-knee-problem-free-in-the-long-run-for-a-distance-r)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr The referenced articles do seem to address the positive effects of minimalist shoes, but they do _not_ seem to address the PF part of the question. Do you have any references on this?

Comment: I've used minimalist shoes for marathon training and the Pikes Peak marathon. The downside is less protection from rocks and hard pavement which makes sense since everyone seems to imply natural minimalist shoes should be used on softer trails. I've gotten sore heels and ankles. Plus one or two calf strains from landing on surfaces smaller than the size of my foot. I dont use them anymore, but if I ran only shorter distances then I would use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There really is no "conclusive" proof at the current time, and not likely to be any in the near future. Part of the problem is that Chi/Pose and the natural styles of running also have a very lucrative market for shoe companies. Pretty much every shoe company now makes minimalist type shoes, and there are entire companies (Newton) that make only fore/mid foot strike shoes, and a lot of the studies have been funded by the company selling the shoes.

A lot of the studies are observational, i.e., they just watch runners and classify them and then review the injuries that they suffer in a year. Part of the problem with some of the studies is that they look at elite runners, and then everyone wants to apply that to the general masses. You can see this with the recommendation for 180 foot strikes a minute being "ideal". This was taken off of a small sampling of elite runners during a high profile marathon. Suddenly your 11 minute a mile weekend warrior is being told he needs to get to 180 foot strikes a minute because Bekele runs that way.

My personal opinion is that people generally self select the strike pattern and gait that naturally suits them at the speed they are currently running. As you get towards the faster end of the field, the more you need to start moving from a rear foot strike to mid/fore foot.

I did find [this study](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~skeleton/pdfs/2012b.pdf) to be very interesting, as it definitively shows over the period of a year that rear foot strikers tend to suffer injuries at twice the rate of fore foot strikers. It also points out that the faster the runner, the more likely they are to fore foot strike. This was done on a group of elite college level cross country runners, and was published this year.

It also dismisses the "heel never touching the ground" strike pattern as it's extremely rare among elite runners.

The other thing that hasn't really been studied is if a mid foot striker wears rear foot strike shoes and that contribution to the injury rate. There are just way too many variables that are unknown in most studies to really nail it down yet, and the shoe companies have no vested interest in doing those kinds of studies.

Comment: I found this article of NY Times that seems to indicate that elite runners (he the Olympic 10k field) comes in all sort of strike flavours - http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/15/myths-of-running-forefoot-barefoot-and-otherwise/?_r=1 - but is does not talk about injuries...

Comment: @TonnyMadsen - I had seen some of that, but not that writeup, thank you. It reinforces my belief that people generally select the strike pattern that best suits them naturally. There are some excellent study links in that article as well.