# Healing severe IT Band Issues

Tags: knee-pain

I've been trying to train for a marathon, but I'm getting IT band discomfort around 3 miles into my runs.  I've tried rest, specific workouts, different shoes, and KT tape, but the discomfort just isn't going away.  I can even feel it a little bit if I just touch the side of my knee where the IT band passes by.  Does anyone have a surefire cure for IT band issues?

Comment: @Jimsan gave you a nice link that includes ITB/TFL stretches, but also includes important strengthening and balance control. This [q/a](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11858/stretches-and-muscle-work-for-supination-or-underpronation) also includes some other intrinsic and extrinsic factors you may need to address like shoes, running surfaces and specific hip muscle weaknesses with a link to a hip strengthening exercise video for ITBS.

Comment: You are welcome - hope it helps.

Comment: Did you consult with an orthopeadecian and a physio subsequently?

Answer (score 2):

I used to regularly suffer with IT band pain whilst running. I started running in January this year and up until approx. 2-3 months ago I would get IT band pain, however it was random as to when it happened. Sometimes it would be a mile into a run, others I could run for 10 miles and have no problems at all. I tried applying a tubi-grip type support to the affected knee and this did give some respite however it did not clear up the problem altogether. I then tried doing stretching exercises specifically focussing on the IT band both before and after runs. You can see examples of such stretches [here](http://www.runnersworld.com/injury-treatment/stretching-and-strengthening-exercises-iliotibial-band-syndrome). Since I started doing these stretches I have had zero IT band trouble. I'm happily doing 40-50 miles a week now at a variety of intensities whereas before I would struggle to do 20 because of IT band pain. This solution may not work for you but it's definitely worth trying as it doesn't cost anything. Failing that, I would recommend consulting a physio for professional advice

Answer (score 0):

Bone chips. Sometimes, a [knee injury](http://www.footsolutions.ca) can break off fragments from the bone or cartilage. These pieces can get stuck in the joint, causing it to freeze up. You may also have pain and swelling.

Bursitis. A bursa is a sac of fluid that cushions and protects your joints. There are several in different parts of your knee. Overuse, a fall, or repeated bending can irritate the bursa, causing pain and swelling. Two types of bursitis are called ''housemaid's knee'' and ''preacher's knee,'' since they are often caused by kneeling. A ''Baker's cyst'' -- a swelling of one of the bursa in the back of the knee -- can also result from injuries and from conditions like [arthritis](http://www.footsolutions.ca).

Comment: The questioner has asked a way for healing, I don't find anything like that in your answer.